# plotting wrong on x axis

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, python-3.8

thank you for reading my question

[image]

I have to plot my data like that. When I plot my data

[image]

I am having an output like this.
Code for reading the data from the file and plotting is below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('data.txt','r') as file2:
    y= [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file2]


    notf2=y[2:] 

    z=[a.rstrip('   ') for a in notf2]
    x_data=[]
    y_data=[]
    for j in range(0, len(z)):
        x_data += [z[j][:3]]            
        y_data += [z[j][5:]]
    x__data=[]
    y__data=[]
    for k in range(0, len(z)):
        x__data += [x_data[k]]
        y__data += [y_data[k]]

    rx=x__data.reverse()
    ry=y__data.reverse()
   

    
        
    #plt.plot(x__data[::-1],y__data, '.')
    plt.plot(x__data,y__data, '.')
    plt.show()
```

I don't understand why it is plotting it different. It is reversing x axis
but when I try to reverse it

```
 plt.plot(x__data[::-1],y__data, '.')
```

it is not fixing it , just showing the same thing. When I plot

```
plt.plot(x__data[::-1],y__data, '.')
plt.plot(x__data,y__data, '.')
```

both of those it is reversing and showing . And I am not even talking about those numbers (black lines) written as if they are labels

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data are strings. You need to convert them to float

Comment: but if they are strings how did I plotted them in the first place are you sure this is the problem

Comment: Yes that is the problem.  Matplotlib treats strings as categorical data and plots the categories in the order they are received.