# Trying to plot .txt file in Matplotlib but I don't know where I'm going wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a .txt file on Jupyter using matplotlib but every time I plot something I just get a straight line. It's meant to resemble a Lennard Jones potential (not a straight line). I am not sure where I am going wrong. Here is my code (ignore the pandas import I haven't used it yet)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


f = open(os.path.expanduser('C:\\Users\\path\\to\\file.txt'))
lines = f.readlines()[1:]

x, y = [], []

for line in lines:
    x.append(line.split()[3])
    y.append(line.split()[10])

f.close()

print(x, y)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[And this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky6lK.png)

Comment: Your data is strings.

Comment: I recommend packages like Pandas to handle tabular data.

Comment: @BigBen what do you mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: As was said [5 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64878052/9245853) in a similar question.

Comment: @BigBen thanks, forgive me for probably being a bit stupid, but in what line would I change the strings to a float? I didn't even realise the numbers were strings in the first place. Just followed a tutorial on plotting .txt file in matplotlib and this is what happened

Comment: I would follow Quang's advice and use Pandas here instead.

Comment: Alrighty I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: @avidominusnox: in case you want to try it without pandas (but I would recommend that too), you can wrap float around your expressions like this: `float(line.split()[3])`, but pandas does this typing stuff for you automatically, if you like.

Comment: @jottbe thanks, I tried that actually but I ended up getting a '' 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable'' error for the 'lines = f.readlines()[1:]' line. I don't know if I need to somehow incorporate the float bit into this line too?

Comment: Then I guess you got your brackets wrong. Because you seem to have put the squared bracket after some expression, that is a function.  It should read `x.append(float(line.split()[3]))` and likewise for `y`.

Comment: @jottbe unfortunately I did do it like that and it still gave me an error :( but I am using pandas now and it is going ok so far except I'm struggling to plot several columns against x from the .txt file I loaded, I've only managed to plot one column

Comment: Just check if the columns actually have the type you expect them to have using `df.dtypes` (exchange df by the variable you use to reference the loaded dataframe). If it isn't as you aspected, you can use `astype('float')` (or int). You probably need some time to read the pandas docs.